# Copy paste every 10 cells range *10 times to a column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, paste

I want to copy & paste every 10 rows, 10  times from column A to column B and so on continuing until the end of column A.

[image: img1]

This is an example of macro I've tried:

```
Sub cpydble()
Dim j As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long


lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row


For i = 1 To lRow Step 10
    For j = 1 To 100 Step 10
    Cells(i, 1).Resize(10).Copy Destination:=Cells(j, 2)

    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

I'm a beginner with VBA and hope you can help with this - thanks in advance.

This is my current result:

[image: img2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting `j` at 1 every time is probably what's messing stuff up. Just find the next open cell for every loop.

```
Sub cpydbl()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim lRow As Long

    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lRow Step 10
        For j = 1 To 10
            Cells(i, 1).Resize(10).Copy Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Next j
    Next i

    Cells(1, 2).Delete xlShiftUp

End Sub
```

The `Offset` starts the copy at row 2, so I delete the empty first cell at the end to move everything up.

Comment: - Nice idea to copy each block to the next free cell below current results in column B +1). *Side note:* I'd suggest to clear column B to allow repeated code execution, if data got changed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
For i = 1 To lRow Step 10
    Range("B" & i & ":B" & i + 9).Value = Range("A1:A10").Value
Next i
```

Note that with the above code, the last iteration will go below the last row in column `A` should it not be a multiple of 10.

Answer (score 1):

**Fully flexibilized code**

In addition to @DickKusleika 's fine code, I demonstrate a fully flexibilized approach using a data array where you can define alternative block size, number of repetitions and start row via constants.

```
Option Explicit                                    ' declaration head of your code module

Sub copyBlocks()
Const SIZE& = 10, REPETITIONS& = 10, STARTROW& = 1 ' define block size, repetions and start row
Dim ws As Worksheet, i&, j&, k&, n&, v             ' declare variables
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")        ' << change to your sheet name
n = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    ' find last row number in column A
n = ((n + SIZE) \ SIZE) * SIZE                     ' round up to full block size of 10 rows
ws.Range("B:B") = ""                               ' clear column B
k = STARTROW                                       ' start row of 1st block series
For i = STARTROW To n Step SIZE                    ' if STARTROW = 1 For i=1, 11, 21, 31 ... To n
    v = ws.Range("A" & i).Resize(SIZE)             ' get next data block (10 rows)
    For j = 1 To REPETITIONS                       ' write eg. 10 data blocks to column B
        ws.Range("B" & (k + (j - 1) * SIZE)).Resize(SIZE) = v
    Next j
    k = k + SIZE * REPETITIONS                     ' get start row of next block series
Next i
End Sub
```

**Notes**

- Declare your variables (and their types) and force yourself to do so by stating `Option Explicit` in the declaration head of your code module; the ampersand sign `&` is short for e.g. `Dim i As Long`. `v` and **all** not explicitly declared variables default to `Variant`.
- Always use fully qualified range references, otherwise values default to the active sheet which might result in wrong values.
- Variable `n` finds the last row number in column A and rounds it up to the full block size of 10 rows.
- You can easily assign range values to a variant 2-dimensional array in one code line, e.g. via `v = ws.Range("A1:E1234")` or `v = ws.Range("A1:A17").Value`. *Further hint* Each member of this array could be addressed by row and column indices. Note that data field arrays getting values from worksheet ranges are *1-based*, so the first value would be addressed as `v(1,1)`.